# C#: Merge Datarows in the datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a data table with the following details.

```
ID     |   VERSION  |   ENTITY
1      |    01      |   A01
1      |    01      |   A02
2      |    01      |   A01
2      |    01      |   A02
```

I want to merge values of  Column ENTITY as below.

```
ID     |   VERSION  |   ENTITY
1      |    01      |   A01/A02
2      |    01      |   A01/A02
```

is there any way we can achieve it using Linq?

Comment: Your actual requirement is grouping the records based on the `ID` column, isn't it?

Comment: My Actual requirements is to group by both ID and Version

Comment: I can have the values like ID = 1 and version = 2

Comment: so the `ENTITY` entries from all group members should be concatenated using `/` as separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by multiple properties by using an anonymous type:

```
var result = list1.GroupBy(x=> new {x.ID, x.VERSION}).Select(
    item => new Example
    {
        ID = item.Key.ID, 
        VERSION = item.Key.VERSION,
        ENTITY = string.Join("/", item.Select(c=>c.ENTITY))
    });
```

Afterwards select the appropriate properties and feed them into a new object of the type you need.

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

In a  `DataTable` you need to access the columns via the `[ ]` operator but the principle of the grouping remains the same:

Examplary DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("VERSION", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("ENTITY", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(1, "01", "A01");
table.Rows.Add(1, "01", "A02");
table.Rows.Add(2, "01", "A01");
table.Rows.Add(2, "01", "A02");
```

The grouping:

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { ID = x["ID"], VERSION = x["VERSION"]}).Select(
    item => new Example
    {
        ID = (int)item.Key.ID,
        VERSION = (string)item.Key.VERSION,
        ENTITY = string.Join("/", item.Select(c => c["ENTITY"]))
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way we can do it without linq? Means iterating through each row?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use your snippet. I am getting error for the line "x.ID, x.VERSION" . system.data.datarow does not contain definition for ID.?

Comment: @akshay sorry, I did not read carefully enough. I edited my answer and posted a version that can works with a datatable. as Result you will get an `IEnumerable<yourType>`. If you use linq, you will always receive such a return type

Comment: @sampatnayak yes of course. You need a separate collection where you will gather the results. But the basic idea would be to iterate through the rows, check for the values in the two collumns and expand the string if it is different. In the end write the values into your separate collection

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to work:

```
var output = from d in DataTable
             group d.ENTITY by new { ID, VERSION } into grp
             select grp;
```

If you are using something like entity framework you may have do use `output.ToList()` to get the value. If you would like to access `ID` and `VERSION` within the code, you can use a class that has the two instead of `new { ID, VERSION }`